# startTimeMillis no longer updates in Google InApp subscription renewal

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, subscription, auto-renewing

This questions is in regards to the `startTimeMillis` field in the `Purchases.subscriptions` object from Google.

If a User purchases something via Android, the App will send purchase data to our Backend for validation and processing. The response form Google is a `Purchases.subscriptions` object that contains data as described here: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/subscriptions
In this object there are two fields `startTimeMillis` and `expiryTimeMillis`.

If the details of the purchase are sent from our Backend to Google *after* the time in `expiryTimeMillis`, then we get back a new object with an updated `expiryTimeMillis`. This means that we are in the "next" renewal period. Our backend creates a new record with this new data. Works fine.

However I am seeing some strangeness in the records of our database. And in the code that we have written.

In the documentation linked to above, it states that the `startTimeMillis` is the initial purchase date of the subscription. So if I bought a subscription today, then 'startTimeMillis' will be today and 'expiryTimeMillis`will be 1 month from now. If I bought the subscription 3 months ago today, then the`startTimeMillis`will be 3 months ago and the`expiryTimeMillis` will be 1 month from today - essentially with 4 months in between the 2 dates.

But this consistent time value for `startTimeMillis` has only been happening this year. I have subscriptions that have been running for over a year and all purchases that were made last year and have been renewing since then have different values for `startTimeMillis`. Basically, the `startTimeMillis` field has always been the start time this the current renewal period.

Then sometime in mid-January this stopped. The `startTimeMillis` now shows the subscription purchase time. I have hundreds of subscriptions like this.

When exactly did this occur? And why? Also, I can't find any documentation or notice that this change has occurred. Can someone shed some light onto what happened here?